# FTP using pexpect.py (Unix)

Tags: python, ftp, pexpect

```
child = pexpect.spawn('ftp XX.XXX.73.64')
child.logfile = sys.stdout
child.expect ('Name .*:')
child.sendline('admin')
child.expect('Password .*:')
child.sendline('XXXXX')
```

Output:
Connected to XX.XXX.73.64.
220 (vsFTPd 2.0.7)
Name (XX.XXX.73.64): admin
admin
331 Please specify the password.
Password:XXXXX

I'm trying to automate FTPing to a switch, but my sendline command for 'admin' seems to be sending 'admin' twice. Thus, my username is incorrect. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `pexpect` on the `ftp` command instead of just using `ftplib`?

Comment: Not an answer, but I agree with abarnert, why aren't you using the std ftplib?  In general, I have found it better to stick with std libs, until there is functionality that I need that is not supplied. Doesn't mean that you don't have a reason, but would be helpful to understand.  Final note: you will almost always get more help and better answers when dealing with std libs.

Comment: @DavidS: Agreed in general… but even if `ftplib` weren't in the stdlib and `pexpect` were, I'd still suggest using a nice API over trying to fight with some program's CLI that wasn't intended to be scripted…

Comment: Please see [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If your goal is "trying to automate FTPing to a switch", ask for help doing that. Showing what you've tried and why it didn't work is always a good idea—but it shouldn't be your whole question.

Comment: I'm sorry, that was not my intent.

Comment: @abarnert Well, can't argue with you here! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be very hard to debug your code without a lot more information. Clearly `sendline` isn't supposed to send the line twice, so something is wrong… but you haven't given us a reproducible test case, or any information beyond those four lines.

But really, things are going to be a lot simpler if you don't try to use `pexpect` in the first place. If you really do need to script a CLI program that wasn't designed for it, `pexpect` is a great option. But if you have an API (or a scriptable app, or etc.), it's always going to be easier. Python includes batteries for a reason, and one of those batteries is [`ftplib`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html):

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP('XX.XXX.73.64', 'admin', 'XXXXX')
```

You can make the `connect` and `login` calls explicit instead of having the constructor do it for you if you need to do anything fancier than the usual… but in this case, you don't, so it's literally a one-liner.

[How to use FTP in Python](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/code-snippets-source-code/how-to-use-ftp-in-python/) looks like a nice tutorial.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to script this for a specific CLI. I believe my error was the expect statement cause now I can connect.

Comment: @user2285010: _Why_ are you trying to script this specific CLI? That CLI is just the `ftp` command. `ftplib` can do everything it can, and more, much more easily. If your goal is "trying to automate FTPing to a switch", you don't need `pexpect` for that.

Comment: I'm trying to transfer from certain directories dynamically. I.e. the user chooses which directory to get the file from. The only way i can do this is to be able to change directories via the client side and I couldn't find out how to do that using th FTPlib.

Comment: If you want to change the server-side directory, that's just [`ftp.cwd`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.cwd). It's in Example 2 of the tutorial I linked to.